# Angularjs filtering json results

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm having trouble filtering a json object using a filter function from a repeater. The filter was working on the first level without issue but now when I try to filter the rest of the collection and then return the scope data if the filter is not defined I get errors.

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/8u23xv5c/14/), I appreciate the help.

```
app.filter('showByfilValue',['ctrl'], function ($scope,ctrl) {
return function (items, word) {
var filtered = [];
  if (typeof word !== 'undefined') {
var letterMatch = new RegExp('^' + word + '$', 'i');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var item = items[i];
 if (letterMatch.test(item.services[0].services[0].serviceName)) {
    filtered.push(item);
  }
}
return filtered;
  } else {
      return data;
  }
 };
});
```

Jimi

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `['ctrl'], function ($scope,ctrl) {...}`? Inject $scope and controller into filter? Don't. Actually it would be `['$scope', 'ctrl', function ($scope,ctrl) {...}]`, but anyway don't. Just pass all variables you need into the filter when you call it: `ng-repeat="item in items | showByfilValue:variable1:variable2:variable3"`

Comment: Hi thanks for answering my question. I removed the parts of the code you recommended. I tried the method that you said but it didn't work. Maybe you can make a change to the fiddle and show me how it's done?

Comment: thanks, your changes made a difference. i'm not getting any errors anymore.